# Website structure folders arrange

Tags: web, structure, directory

I'm trying to get to know what would be the correct structure for my website folder at the host panel, I  basically placed everything within the public_html or something folder using Filezilla, but when I enter my website and I go to the navbar and click either the "reviews" or other tabs, I'm correctly redirected to each of them.

The problem comes when I try access the home page from either the "reviews", "entrevistas" or others, I would either get an error or just nothing happens. I don't know if is an error of the structure of a coding issue.

Comment: The problem does not seem exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a look for example at the bootstrap folder structure

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/getting-started.html

2. search for

   website folder structure

to find articles about the topic.

Comment: ty! i will take a look at that!